# Python - How can I select this element?

Tags: python, css, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to figure out how to select this element. It's the last iteration of the class on the webpage. The id will change every week. The source is below:

```
</tr><tr>
        <td>Disney Mainline</td><td>
                            <a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchTyp" class="cls_arw arw_blue" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$lnkSchTyp','')"></a>
                        </td><td>Oct 15, 2017</td><td>
                            <a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_lnkSchDist" class="cls_arw arw_grey" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$lnkSchDist','')"></a>
                        </td><td>Oct 03, 2017 06:00 PM</td><td>15</td><td>Oct 05, 2017 03:30 PM</td><td>80</td><td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnApp_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnApp_Id" value="138" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnApp_Sch_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnApp_Sch_Id" value="48178" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnApp_Grp_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnApp_Grp_Id" value="686" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnWk_Strt_Date" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnWk_Strt_Date" value="10/15/2017 00:00:00" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnOffset" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnOffset" value="-300" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl02$hdnPrivType" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl02_hdnPrivType" value="e" />
                        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>Disney Mainline</td><td>
                            <a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_lnkSchTyp" class="cls_arw arw_blue" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$lnkSchTyp','')"></a>
                        </td><td>Oct 22, 2017</td><td>
                            <a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_lnkSchDist" class="cls_arw arw_grey" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$lnkSchDist','')"></a>
                        </td><td>Oct 10, 2017 10:21 AM</td><td>15</td><td>Oct 12, 2017 03:30 PM</td><td>80</td><td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnApp_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnApp_Id" value="138" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnApp_Sch_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnApp_Sch_Id" value="48344" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnApp_Grp_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnApp_Grp_Id" value="686" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnWk_Strt_Date" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnWk_Strt_Date" value="10/22/2017 00:00:00" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnOffset" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnOffset" value="-300" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl03$hdnPrivType" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl03_hdnPrivType" value="e" />
                        </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>Disney Mainline</td><td>
                            <a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl04_lnkSchTyp" class="cls_arw arw_blue" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl04$lnkSchTyp','')"></a>
                        </td><td>Oct 29, 2017</td><td>
                            <a id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl04_lnkSchDist" class="cls_arw arw_grey" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl04$lnkSchDist','')"></a>
                        </td><td>Oct 17, 2017 06:00 PM</td><td>15</td><td>Oct 19, 2017 03:30 PM</td><td>80</td><td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl04$hdnApp_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl04_hdnApp_Id" value="138" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl04$hdnApp_Sch_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl04_hdnApp_Sch_Id" value="48471" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl04$hdnApp_Grp_Id" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl04_hdnApp_Grp_Id" value="686" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl04$hdnWk_Strt_Date" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl04_hdnWk_Strt_Date" value="10/29/2017 00:00:00" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl04$hdnOffset" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl04_hdnOffset" value="-300" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cphMain$gdvSchdRel$ctl04$hdnPrivType" id="ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl04_hdnPrivType" value="e" />
                        </td>
    </tr>
```

I'm wanting to select the last iteration of the class "cls_arw arw_blue" so that it will take me to its designated link. But I haven't been able to figure it out.

I've tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("cls_arw arw_blue")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl04_lnkSchTyp")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.cls_arw arw_blue")
```

*Note:* I realize that, if successful, my attempts would only have found the first element under those conditions, but it hasn't even been able to find the element based off of what I've tried. When I do figure out how to find the element, I would also need help finding the last iteration of it on the page.

Comment: Do you have a url by chance so I can test this myself? Using the code you provided with BeautifulSoup, I'm able to find all iterations of that class and locate the last one. But I can't test in selenium without the url.

Comment: @jarcobi889, the website requires login information to be able to view the webpage. We can exchange skype info or email to talk further. But I can't post login credentials on here.

Answer (score 0):

How about `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cls_arw arw_blue")[-1]` note that it's elements plural not just element.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question we can locate/identify all of the the intended elements and invoke `click()` method on them.

Now, as you are trying to locate/identify the last instance of the class `cls_arw arw_blue` you can use the following option with `xpath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(.,'Disney Mainline')]//following::td/a[@class='cls_arw arw_blue'][starts-with(@id,'ctl00_cphMain_gdvSchdRel_ctl')]"));
```

We can be more generic as follows :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(.,'Disney Mainline')]//following::td[1]/a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if spaces in class names are allowed (so I can't say if the page source or webdriver is wrong here).
Anyway, repacing the " " in the search for the class name by "." makes it work.

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cls_arw.arw_blue')`

And, as said above by jarcobi889, "find_element**s**_" and picking the last one will be your next step.

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cls_arw.arw_blue')[-1]`